# what happen if I don't use Foreign key explicitly in EF?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6

I am working on my Major Project. I come across a problem where I have many to many relation between:

1. "User" Table and "BlogPost" Table.
2. "User" Table and "Tag" Table.
   I am using Entity Framework 6.0

here is My code...

```
public class BlogPost
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TagName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Tag> Intrests { get; set; }

    public ICollection<BlogPost> BlogPosts { get; set; }
}
```

if I am using the above code I am getting expected schema. i.e.
I got five tables.   User, BlogPost, Tag, TagUser, UserBlogPost

where User contains only: Id, Name, and Age.
TagUser and UserBlogPost contains primary key of User and their own table as well to create many to many relationship between them.

and If I explicitly create Foreign Key property for My all Navigation property like this:

```
public class BlogPost
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TagName { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Tag> Intrests { get; set; }

    public int BlogPostId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BlogPost> BlogPosts { get; set; }
}
```

I get different result.
here User Table contains: Id, Name, Age and TagId, BlogPostId as well.
and Tag and BlogPost table contains foreign key referring to User table.
and also it has TagUser and UserBlogPost tables as well.

So if I don't create Foreign key property in My Classes, then is there any problem or not. how can I handle this situation?
please help...

Comment: What would be the function of the `UserId` fields?

Comment: @GertArnold: I am using UserId to uniquely identify each user. And it is serve as a foreign key in Tag and BlogPost.

I mean it does not provide any other functionality than these.

Comment: Sure, but why would you need these keys? What is their role? They're entirely different than the `Users` collections.

Comment: @GertArnold: Sir I am creating a Blog, and there are other classes too. Here One User can post multiple Blog Posts(BlogPost) and one User can have multiple Tags(Tags are like Interests) and multiple user can have same Tag.

Comment: OK, one last try. Why would a `Tag` need a reference to *one* user? As you say, a Tag has multiple users. I feel you don't understand what you're doing when adding a `UserId` (or `TagId and `BlogPostId` to `User`).